# Moving data from BDE Paradox Database to SQLite FireDAC Database

Tags: sqlite, delphi, migrate, firedac, bde

My job gave me a lengthy task, and I'm wondering if there is a faster way to move the data from the old database to the new one.

Currently, we have a program that uses the BDE database, and I was tasked with migrating it to a SQLite database.

All the old BDE components were already removed, and I'm working on a second program that would run when you opened the first program and then move all the data from the old DB files into the new one.

So, long story short, I'm wondering if there is a faster way of doing it instead of connecting to a table, specifying the fields, setting the new fields equal to the old fields, posting it, and then disconnecting from the table.

Then I have to do all that again for the next table.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: FDTable has a CopyDataSet method which will do the work if the fields are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Brian. I didn't even know that function existed. The CopyDataSet method is exactly what I was looking for.